# The Redis cache used by CodeIgniter is not a pure string and cannot be share with other languages

Tags: codeigniter, redis, continuous-integration

PHP CodeIgniter demo code: :

```
// using redis cache
$cache = Services::cache();
$cache->save("test-aaaaaaaa", "hahaha", 60 * 10);
```

I think it should be a pure string like this:

```
Key: test-aaaaaaaa
Type: string
Value: hahaha
```

But the final stored result is this：

```
Key: test-aaaaaaaa
Type: hash
Value: [__ci_type:string, __ci_value:hahaha]
```

So the result is CI specific and cannot be shared with other languages.

Is there any good solution to use redis pure string for CI

CodeIgniter redis value use pure string, not hash